# How can I create a reference for javascript library?

Tags: javascript, libraries

I created a plugin-based web application, each one of the plugins is completely an independent web project also I created my own javascript library in the host application that should be used in every plugins, so I want to create a reference for my javascript library to use in every plugin project for getting intellisense in visual studio environment at development time.

Is there any best practice to be used for this issue?

Comment: No use for TypeScript if the library is already written in JS. @MehrdadBahrainy: You want to automatically include IntelliSense references in VisualStudio projects...did I get you right?

Comment: @FabianLauer yes you are right. I create a javascript library in host project and it should be applied in plugins projects then when the plugins are inserted into the host application they can use the library

Comment: You can use `/// <reference path="../YourScript.js" />` for referencing scripts on your local disk. I'm not sure if this works for protocols, say http, too, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reference tag on visual studio. There are four usage patterns:

1- to reference another javascript file use

```
/// <reference path="someFolder/someScriptFile.js" />
```

2- reference to a Web Service

```
/// <reference path="somepath/WCFService.svc" />
/// <reference path="somepath/asmxService.asmx" />
```

3- reference t a Web Page

```
/// <reference path="somepath/default.aspx" />
```

4- reference to an Embedded Resource

```
/// <reference name="resource-name" />
/// <reference name="resource-name" assembly="assembly-name" />
```

**Note**:
You can use app-relative paths (~/folder/file) to make your references more robust

Hope it helps.

**update:** you can use it in .html, .aspx, .cshtml and .js files.

**Update2:** if the path is not in your project you can add an existing file as a LinkedItem in visual studio **(Add As Link)** and add the LinkItem path to the path of reference tag.